# Make sure you read the terms of this riddle!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

The first part of my first part? You should already know.
The last part of my first part, is men’s most common foe.
The whole of my first part, weird as it might be,
Is the lack of my first part’s last part. There, you see?
The first part of my last part is the first part of many,
Of mussels, of waivers, of school sessions aplenty.
The last part of my last part is the last part of more,
Of a field, and one’s height, and a beast you abhor.
The whole of my last part isn’t an actual word,
But rhymes with the whole of plants, bugs, squirrels, and birds.
Combined all my parts, and together they yield:
The secrets one needs to enter a field

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it

> **Nomenclature**

The first part of my first part? You should already know.

> Not 100% sure on reasoning of this part, but **No** is a homophone of "know".

The last part of my first part is men's most common foe.

> **Men** are men's own most common enemy *Thanks @jafe!*

The whole of my first part, weird as it might be,
Is the lack of my first part’s last part. There, you see?

> **Nomen**. Just "no men".

The first part of my last part is the first part of many,
Of mussels, of waivers, of school sessions aplenty.

> **Cla**ms, **Cla**uses, **Cla**sses *Thanks @jafe for this part too!*

The last part of my last part is the last part of more,
Of a field, and one’s height, and a beast you abhor.

> Pas**ture**, Sta**ture**, Crea**ture**.

The whole of my last part isn’t an actual word,
But rhymes with the whole of plants, bugs, squirrels, and birds.

> **Clature**. Not a word, but rhymes with "Nature"

Combined all my parts, and together they yield:
The secrets one needs to enter a field

> **Nomenclature**. The body or system of names used in a particular specialist field.

Comment: Nicely done, Timoris! Props to @jafe for solving some of the clues as well. You're right on with your logic in every line

Answer (score 6):

Partial

The last part of my first part, is men’s most common foe.

> A man's most common enemy is the **man** himself.

The whole of my first part, weird as it might be,
Is the lack of my first part’s last part. There, you see?

> Lack of "man", ending with "man"... Maybe **woman**?

The first part of my last part is the first part of many,
Of mussels, of waivers, of school sessions aplenty.

> Clams, clauses and classes all begin with **cla**.